# Django link to a specific users profile page

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, request

I have a social media website that will allow a user to view another users profile page by clicking their username from one of their posts that appears in the feed section of my page. I have view_profile view created but need to pass in the desired users username into the view, to only show posts, activity, etc... made by that specific user. How do i pass the username into my view?

view_profile.html

```
<section id="main_feed_section" class="feed_sections">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post_main_container">
            <section class="post_title">
                <h1> <a href="{% url 'view_profile' %}">{{ post.user_id.username }}</a>{{ post.title }}</h1>
            </section>

            <section class="post_main_body">
                <p>{{ post.caption }}</p>
            </section>

            <section class="post_footer">
                <p>{{ post.date_posted }}</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

views.py

```
def view_profile(request):   
    account = "logan9997" #if a post made by logan9997 was clicked
    posts = [post for post in Posts.objects.all()
    if post.user_id.username == account]

    followers = [follower for follower in Relationships.objects.all()
    if follower.acc_followed_id.username == account]

    context = {
        "title":account,
        "posts":posts,
        "followers":followers
    }
    return render(request, "myApp/view_profile.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("home/", views.home, name="home"),
    path("create_post/", views.create_post, name="create_post"),
    path('view_profile/<str:username>', views.view_profile, name="view_profile"), 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to your view:

```
def view_profile(request, account):
    ...
```

And urls:

```
path('view_profile/<str:account>', ...)
```

Then you can go to url: `localhost:8000/view_profile/logan9997`.

You can do it better with `User` id:

```
path('view_profile/<int:pk>', ...)

def view_profile(request, pk):
    account = User.objects.get(id=pk).username
    ...
```

And go for: `localhost:8000/view_profile/1`

This is very not Django-style:

```
posts = [post for post in Posts.objects.all()
if post.user_id.username == account]
```

Use `filter()` method instead:

```
posts = Posts.objects.filter(user_id__username=account)
# and
followers = Relationships.objects.filter(acc_followed_id__username=account)
```

Comment: i still get a 404 error. In my search bar: http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_profile/?user_id=2

Comment: @logan_9997 try `/view_profile/2` ;)

Comment: still doesn't seem to work

Comment: i've added my urls.py if that is any use